# Microsoft InfoPath "Outlook must be set as default e-mail program"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-infopath

When I try to publish an InfoPath 2007 form, I get the following message:

> To use this feature, Microsoft Office 2007 must be set as the default e-mail program.

However, Outlook *is* configured as default e-mail program already. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of InfoPath Publishing Wizard]

I verified that Microsoft Outlook is the default e-mail program in two ways:

- I went to Control Panel > Internet Settings -> ... -> Default Programs
- I tried and entered mailto:myown-e-mail-address in Firefox and it opened Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same problem recently and have also looked online for solutions, without much success. Here are a few ones worth considering:

- Run repair on your Office 2007 (instructions can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924614))
- Verify that Outlook is really your default mail client. To do this, go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Options > Manage browser add-ons > Programs> Internet Programs.
- If all else fails, try closing Outlook when sending your forms in InfoPath.

Comment: Thanks, Melissa. I did verify that Outlook is the default (updated my question). I will try the "close Outlook" trick and the repair-office approach and see whether it helps. (I'll not be able to do that before March though...)